# Why did Itori want information about the ghoul restaurant?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

In Tokyo Ghoul manga, Itori made a trade with Kaneki in which he must give her information about the Ghoul Restaurant in exchange for information about the person who is responsible for the incident involving the steel beams. Why did she want that information? Was it that important to risk Kaneki's life for it?